# A twisted proxy that logs all traffic

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I am trying to write a proxy in Twisted that logs all traffic going through it in both directions. So far I can capture requests (GET, POST, etc.) but not the responses (can't see html of webpages).

```
from twisted.web import proxy, http
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.protocols import basic
#log.startLogging(sys.stdout)


class MyProxy(proxy.Proxy):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        # Modify the data here
        print data
        # perform the default functionality on modified data 
        return proxy.Proxy.dataReceived(self, data)

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
        #protocol = proxy.Proxy
        protocol=MyProxy


reactor.listenTCP(8080, ProxyFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Surely there is a method for data going the other way? Perhaps something to do with a "response".

Comment: see [this answer that shows how to access responses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9469400/4279).