# HTTP two-way proxy using Twisted

Tags: proxy, twisted

I'm working on a two-way HTTP proxy that that forwards requests from the web browser to a randomly selected third-party proxy and then returns the response to the web browser.

Client -> Proxy -> ([Third-party Proxy 1] or [Third-party Proxy 2]) -> Proxy -> Client

Eventually I want to be able to inspect and change the headers, body, and status code of the response from the third-party proxy and then send the altered response back to the web browser.

This is what I have so far.  It's adapted from [an implementation by Sujit Pal](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2010/03/http-debug-proxy-with-twisted.html).   The author claims it has some bugs but doesn't offer much detail or how to fix them.  It works for very small webpages such as www.example.com, but for anything larger it gets part way through the page resource downloads and then stops.  It appears to have something to do with one or both of the connections closing prematurely but I can't see how that is happening.  This is my first experience with twisted and I don't know how to debug this.  What am I doing wrong?

```py
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.web import http

class HttpClientProtocol(http.HTTPChannel):
    def __init__(self, serverTransport):
        self.serverTransport = serverTransport

    def sendMessage(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.serverTransport.write(self.data)
        self.serverTransport.loseConnection()

class HttpServerProtocol(http.HTTPChannel):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        third_party_proxy_host, third_party_proxy_port = random.choice([
            ('127.0.0.1', 8080),
            ('127.0.0.1', 8081)

        client = protocol.ClientCreator(reactor, HttpClientProtocol, self.transport)
        d = client.connectTCP(third_party_proxy_host, third_party_proxy_port)
        d.addCallback(self.forwardToClient, data)

    def forwardToClient(self, client, data):
        client.sendMessage(data)

class MyHTTPFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
    protocol = HttpServerProtocol

reactor.listenTCP(8000, MyHTTPFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: related: [Python - Twisted, Proxy and modifying content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9465236/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution.  I copied the code for twisted.web.proxy out of the Twisted module and altered it to suit my purposes.  It does not have the same issues as the code above and works great.