# Modify html from simple proxy in Twisted

Tags: python, html, proxy, twisted, reverse-proxy

I wrote a simple proxy script in Twisted and It works just fine:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server
site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('example.com', 80, ''.encode("utf-8")))
reactor.listenTCP(80, site)
reactor.run()
```

The only problem is, I would like to modify the html that my script fetches from the 3rd party site before it renders the resource on my server. I'm not sure where in `twisted/web/proxy.py` I would insert/modify the code to do so.

Comment: You are using `ReverseProxyResource`, but what you are describing sounds like a (forward) proxy to me. I think you will find this thread useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465236/python-twisted-proxy-and-modifying-content.

Comment: thanks, that actually solved the problem!